# Getting around "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue" error when web scraping w/ Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I recently wrote a script to scrape the front-end of a website, but recently have run into issues with enabling Javascript and cookies so I can pull the data. I'm not sure if this is a new captcha that was implemented, but have made several attempts at getting around this error, as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Scripts/scrape/untitled.py", line 21, in <module>
    data = DuneData('01GZ9A6BJ85ZJSQWVG2RVXY2XJ',188664)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Scripts/scrape/untitled.py", line 16, in DuneData
    data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 917, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Just a moment...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet">
    

</head>
<body class="no-js">
    <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
    <div class="main-content">
        <noscript>
            <div id="challenge-error-title">
                <div class="h2">
                    <span class="icon-wrapper">
                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
                    </span>
                    <span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </noscript>
        <div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=7caf65968a49e71a')"></div>
        <form id="challenge-form" action="/v1/graphql?__cf_chl_f_tk=blBqvLjLbA8FPaIGpKKwah.JvllhTMlA.UhXCSc1XXs-1684699134-0-gaNycGzNDPs" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="md" value="295Z8glK_610pCxAx3lV2daoYOQlQfzgh9M8J.xym9Q-1684699134-0-AYkSDJTle9beyLVvfmcSmQFGxQJa_7grQNKxDDtnS3Uk3LAzUVM0pGZldf1kAk0588IkaC4OxYsJktXypW8XxQuvLNh4i5A5s-jvQ8PLTd2GDCy2ICGwmMKEmZE2L29YLKvea2XdHC_2KfLGehRoOi9ZuVHOPj6OD75anQdCnFWacAH1Rtn5w9HBtFz_aIxardEYmJ2jpeCisFBFfYpq23uX29XMmyGJPpIXV3186PZMlyFyGT9Ho3E5JIL-sICGvzDjZThj-Z7MCkH4qIAip85TBQPWz2rg0MSteZ7ivlq_vFZ6pgBkcuW2fvDYRRFRchjtezQ7bA1O3CavYjses5IiU7UwO_-lgnXGZLN0NQua8x8N34WKyJfOIKf5EKaFSHqoTTFTZSt_DuAH0BtMgNUffY-XGgu7o8PA9p_l-QrHFXVYB8BOJZbA9NhYjsBk3d_hq6NzQ_T748Nbp9jofxv1NL8vykCZTgKlRgiHxu686nH55DW0rfgBWsoWU6o1JbPIJ8WuWrQES2LklH22fOVFg6YsCpQuk-9ZvvCGUT_64Q7SCJ2xrwvTXASkyuQUIwYD9-q3Ja9VVAPeVSPE0_el-4-UGL10iSw8AIubzzbwyb7Y8Ps8lWXlV5NrhIMwquLX19LWiUqPDaNnnSwTStoFYIM55HGD9rUL0FZhz_AGoJDBP5qGFE7-qR2YjyZ7R2oLQON9aR3oqz5hLIKxgK748uZ-HqX48L84v9UTZLLyaJVaKmJosTKCYhyxdXquaaxnftWP3h8alAjXfLb2dPofVOh9YZCIE8n0S0Wp4MZ7hNnSf4XT-A9vDCuJSj_3iubfaZg1rpFpzoXeARnAJYwwO3ZNsai51v5lyYmWalpHR7QzDypX99PATde6cOi_JwZouz5PanOHzgE5QZyqcf1RDR_GvoGDZPWEiy0v44saewnWtW6dg8BhxUVV9kd-n1MhW3WG-rrVgATKFst2FvVm33ULu69ff_cLa3H5Sw4fvNLSfpT5mvs57Yu9wEdj9RX9tzZAcULzOgDywwZXnkxTsZEutxCHgkcS5SWPC5CRn_4R-zLv6a2iQcl2J0igYaI35AAg0QJg1nuwltsJZPxIjM7Yyb13BhGRdtRZd6zj4CpFJB8F4EkhrTok4S08GE6Omol66xy6emsAPui-j5iOHoqKHYjECxjDKDmE4A5RpYE2NrY45m9ENtbuTN73A_gpqT0hRGsZX93QIUJJw0aCWfxxaMfdGMNUh0gQYfgRiyZpJdNDKYaaCUYX55WniybSlLkTjY_K8fVZqMLXYXE1PeMqebL04jsN6cqWP7Ch_-Ng7_zTqY_-keFgrf6Jg5Cd2SuDcMoNmXIvRIgON2BavVyawTE-c_fnpeC9p_GebCScrMIBvZf63WhEoEu-UlCWm21762jXgKptb3Y7XCelpzxTjmHumlxyzcpHKcJKR3OksTqQzTXjYC1qn52mVVO7arsZIwNXH90njhOXV_e6qOeqZsW-kmoF6NyxuY0WHuMEWesFbJstEQuYD-ni1ZyvqZpfaQwWSEMh203nh30rIK36MpfHp2O0TrIYITkoeQPZfqvAnY1st2EkfJMurJCbboJjFsPYHvV_hFORCCs6lBAjxsDUEOKBVHbIoxa9s1DtkK48UpHzHZdXASJB_5UZXgdksYV6QfFKEsbm7yaPQJxiEXxo0ZMonHT2IX7stErAZWWFOwbvfflxDAD_VeCkaMcGX2IlQiuqDfO-nNVB69jPTjYhJIBcqNN4aDUUBBKwlhQwNfpfq76w9TOZw6Xg7hE6zZpbYGLfjn2EX9W7Ei46ZrrAndKSjBqMUGYGLPoGv85WMwRnxMg-voHXWaulJzaEpKuUPhYryrRtb2v695mbcurPnZI_VcLsZ-yu1WhKLfCl_g9mvUPmNdM84Sb4zKSOVlMjdCQz899kEeYbAeES_WxSG2Qcgc3zk2P6iuqYy9heGR8xfCaqjw-xHGjSIsED8cdf9W_N6TIulV7ImQwyacAREosCu9qo7IQurdvK3oZxli0gFLCpqI3MisdhSQF9RSg3Cxp2oYoZV8Jaxbu903FQ3IM78CzgjkT78bmAKBr-i71ypKjCxgqMF2VVkiRV_aIWUm35T7hAzbXoOY51CE5xT2n0a_LYokAvQDKrsmDKb7dJ1xGjXmntZQXvakacrzBFi7dPFtxTxXoUKYAoZoZLQoh8NDLDbA4kA6IljZdc4YxtnjKineArbW3wc3U6iKb0rX4SQGoSOKxKwDf3K1i2JXUqstR_vL-1ksQr7voa29TeKgwFH-rwYDWuIy5Ny7GLu_xJM9qFEOFQ16zSgZn9NmBEdq7lJEBzmXR2ShmbffPYfssWqtw3EJMWy1Khm98X_u-cZNMYZ4pc_MfynVn8czDpgJ1VEQkNi2PezLUy7PI1lgdb2ENIE_WL2tuFhwifwJq7mUWgNzPJb9SZcMTahufMRTndZ-852vtxt-n8QzrPCJJYUjYvasqJkcrmYgyT6rINdhBFVlu2ROAyi8Z-J8_olGjU5YPL-L_JbqdBixzmGuG_OYnFLJmeuufmaY2-oCE4zcCcPFym7YC8kNjARiCWKM1P72WhvoiS_SdvbQ6sO6YklgUz9jPR1ZkxUp4_QebsA_mIWmeEAiNdgXIa8wfOiUH_bTd7IbvFYg6M59EZ_e8dv_XUEji1IE5eZpSMmhg3daPKnL6-Y-M4e6nFSX_iuq4SEk0k5GWcG9hdBScB-QQyTIanCq6o5-KfPanSsSDLH8o1-on3N5XaBktHn_Ob6gQMINNlPxziVLM-ImnM-L6dMAX2qRm1s7nvc16oUoJXaDmD-xNYEAXZAhLceZqH4zloq0EdwmjrknKITaSc3dCrmwZMBZPiTd3wEZhBg5GXSjcaxzX1QupGMkFmzqBN70ACQnumXQX-DQbvSxE_ao-sbo2dnWeOu8mdF2dcDU-1paVhEQ7eR1xdXmvF_tMyek_-uNRixMXcRcB0w59_nZ9M_inAq3bsslAKCoJUSwRAhngChQdE209MtX8sSbbueh2tSCbRXCTL0cLho4s8pQ6gYIWklvgHzUDW4ZuXt8HfDdXnAPbeFxQ4aZRu9sLVJ4Tc06p7lyiXmjoKMsFc68_eqHAtlNUpY2V20ayVzZ4cje1_Se_WIF23SvhtMVBpAC8KFqIgR5DB8_sgVC_y3kU8Booh50OmxzVDA7jvp6loiKbwg12pWhzS2LAjBE85-qAWXn55jtV4rKLs9uYhVaWOfkozhw">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function(){
        window._cf_chl_opt={
            cvId: '2',
            cZone: 'app-api.dune.com',
            cType: 'managed',
            cNounce: '65522',
            cRay: '7caf65968a49e71a',
            cHash: '6c4060ac4ff2016',
            cUPMDTk: "\/v1\/graphql?__cf_chl_tk=blBqvLjLbA8FPaIGpKKwah.JvllhTMlA.UhXCSc1XXs-1684699134-0-gaNycGzNDPs",
            cFPWv: 'g',
            cTTimeMs: '1000',
            cMTimeMs: '0',
            cTplV: 5,
            cTplB: 'cf',
            cK: "",
            cRq: {
                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAtYXBpLmR1bmUuY29tL3YxL2dyYXBocWw=',
                ra: 'TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKE1hY2ludG9zaDsgSW50ZWwgTWFjIE9TIFggMTBfMTFfNSkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzUwLjAuMjY2MS4xMDIgU2FmYXJpLzUzNy4zNg==',
                rm: 'UE9TVA==',
                d: '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',
                t: 'MTY4NDY5OTEzNC40ODYwMDA=',
                m: 'M8BdHRfTrOf1LRwcXamVDQjRvhPG/MZcC1/YvCerKWM=',
                i1: 'KAhWT5sfGsmG/7wBM0w6HA==',
                i2: 'PblavcYHIGXiH36OyaJAng==',
                zh: 'GMVzRUL66vF6Z+RS/U7IfESF77Uae1L4u0J3S5ERVB8=',
                uh: 'MJnL4yXqlDXgoEFDXJrrYdndq9vyeF7u7u/p5sDi8wY=',
                hh: '5gwOidb9xMEjxVD8VFukAZuTqZw/xQPgB7PhXIdMr9A=',
            }
        };
        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=7caf65968a49e71a');
        trkjs.setAttribute('alt', '');
        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo = document.createElement('script');
        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=7caf65968a49e71a';
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length - window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/v1\/graphql?__cf_chl_rt_tk=blBqvLjLbA8FPaIGpKKwah.JvllhTMlA.UhXCSc1XXs-1684699134-0-gaNycGzNDPs" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>


</body>
</html>
: 0
```

Anyone have suggestions, thoughts, or ideas? My code is down below.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def DuneData(execution_id, query_id):
    api_url = "https://app-api.dune.com/v1/graphql"
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    payload = {
        "operationName": "GetExecution",
        "query": "query GetExecution($execution_id: String!, $query_id: Int!, $parameters: [Parameter!]!) {\n  get_execution(\n    execution_id: $execution_id\n    query_id: $query_id\n    parameters: $parameters\n  ) {\n    execution_queued {\n      execution_id\n      execution_user_id\n      position\n      execution_type\n      created_at\n      __typename\n    }\n    execution_running {\n      execution_id\n      execution_user_id\n      execution_type\n      started_at\n      created_at\n      __typename\n    }\n    execution_succeeded {\n      execution_id\n      runtime_seconds\n      generated_at\n      columns\n      data\n      __typename\n    }\n    execution_failed {\n      execution_id\n      type\n      message\n      metadata {\n        line\n        column\n        hint\n        __typename\n      }\n      runtime_seconds\n      generated_at\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n",
        "variables": {
            "execution_id": execution_id,
            "parameters": [],
            "query_id": query_id}}

    data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"]["get_execution"]["execution_succeeded"]["data"])
    return(df)


data = DuneData('01GZ9A6BJ85ZJSQWVG2RVXY2XJ',188664)
dates = data['date'].tolist()
dates = [x.split('T')[0] for x in dates]
loans = data['Total Value Locked'].tolist()

print(dates, loans)
```

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. Where did you get that graphql endpoint from? What's `execution_id` and `query_id`? What's your desired output?

Comment: @baduker The endpoint was from chrome dev tools. The execution_id and query_id are inputs necessary to scrape the website, which can be found under the respective graphql in the network tab of chrome dev tools. 

My desired output is the data of the tables found in a query with the respective execution_id and query_id.